# Length of orbits in group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group, with $|G|=40,$ and $X$ a set with $|X|=67$ and $G$ act on $X.$
There are $5$ orbits for this action of $G$ on $X.$

How many lists of orbits lengths there are?

I know that the leght of an orbit divides the order of the group $G$ and that the sum of orbits length is equal the order of the set $X$, but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some *Mathematica* code to get the possible lists of orbits:

```
IntegerPartitions[67, {5}, Divisors[40]]
```

There are six such partitions, and so there are six possible actions here.

To do this by hand, it's not *that* bad to just try some things out (although obviously proofs by enumeration/exhaustion are annoying).  First of all, note that $67/4=13.5$.  This means that the list can't consist of orbits of size less than 10. So, start with a list consisting of orbits no larger than 20.  Since $20+10+10+10+10 = 60 < 67$ but $20+20+10+10+10 = 70$, it's clear that there needs to be at least one orbit of size 40 or two orbits of size 20.

From there, it's a matter of trying things out.  For instance, for a list with exactly two orbits of size 20 (and none of size 40), we need the three final orbits to sum to $67-40=27$.  Quickly playing around with the numbers 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, and 10 yields nothing that works: since $8+8+8=24$, there needs to be at least one 10, so can we find two orbits that sum to 17?  Clearly not.  Etc.